Calculate the average across multiple columns and looking up a condition
I am trying to average by each month over the last three years. I want to calculate it for each project, but without specifically matching it/tying it to the row (as when more projects are added it is done alphabetically and shifts the rows).
I have tried, but it keeps giving me an error:
=AVERAGEIF(INDEX(G21:P25,MATCH(R24,G23:G25,0),0),H21:P21,S22)




Project
Jan 20
Feb 20
Mar 20
Jan 21
Feb 21
Mar 21
Jan 22
Feb 22
Mar 22




Minnie
200
210
208
199
215
205
196
212
204


Moon
10
10
20
10
11
17
10
10
18


Pluto
0
0
100
300
310
308
315
310
305



With the output table like:



Project
Jan
Feb
Mar




Minnie
198.33




Pluto





Moon







Are the dates real dates or strings?

Here is one more way to accomplish the desired output using one single dynamic array formula:


• Formula used in cell A6
=LET(
     a, A1:A4,
     b, TEXT(B1:J1,"mmmm"),
     c, UNIQUE(b,1),
     d, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(DROP(a,1)),COLUMNS(c),LAMBDA(x,y,
        AVERAGE(INDEX(FILTER(B2:J4,INDEX(c,,y)=b,0),x)))),
     HSTACK(a,VSTACK(c,d)))


If you have access to PIVOTBY() then :
=LET(
     a, TOCOL(IF(B2:J4<>"",A2:A4,NA()),2),
     b, TOCOL(IF(B2:J4<>"",B1:J1,NA()),2),
     c, TOCOL(IF(B2:J4<>"",B2:J4,NA()),2),
     PIVOTBY(a,TEXT(b,"m-mmmm"),c,AVERAGE,,0,,0))



Considering everything you stated, the solution should be very simple:
[L2 and fill to right then down as much as required]=AVERAGE(B2,E2,H2)


While the table structure is expected to be constant, you can fill down the formula (3 cells) for new projects.
Moreover, it can work automatically if you convert the range into the Excel table:


The names in the output table are not in the same order as the data table.  Not sure if that's on purpose.

@Excellor Which names?

First table has (from top to bottom): Minnie, Moon, Plut; while second table has: Minnie, Pluto, Moon; (project names) just slight details I guess, it's not quite clear from the question.

@Excellor I guess it should be aligned with projects as depicted by OP and me. It conforms question's description.

How is it going?

A couple more dynamic array variants for MS365 include...
GROUPBY:
=LET(
   grp, TRANSPOSE(GROUPBY(TOCOL(MONTH(B1:J1)), TRANSPOSE(B2:J4), AVERAGE,, 0)),
   HSTACK(A1:A4, VSTACK(TEXT(TAKE(grp, 1)*29, "mmmm"), DROP(grp, 1)))
)


REDUCE-BYROW:
=LET(
    hdr, TEXT(B1:J1, "mmmm"),
    unq, UNIQUE(hdr, 1),
    avg, REDUCE(A2:A4, unq, LAMBDA(a,v, HSTACK(a, BYROW(FILTER(B2:J4, hdr=v), AVERAGE)))),
    VSTACK(HSTACK("Project", unq), avg)
)

Note: if eta-lambdas are not yet available in your version of Excel, use LAMBDA(r, AVERAGE(r)) for the [function] argument of BYROW instead of just AVERAGE.

Here's one possible solution, but it requires Excel 365.
=BYROW(FILTER(INDEX($G$21:$O$23,XMATCH(F16,$F$21:$F$23),0),MONTH($G$20:$O$20)=1),LAMBDA(a,AVERAGE(a)))

With:
$G$21:$O$23 being your data set (values only);
F16 is your 'wanted' person/row;
$F$21:$F$23 being the list of persons;
$G$20:$O$20 is your row of dates, in date format (so not textstring);
MONTH($G$20:$O$20)=1 selects the prefered month, with 1 being January. If you like this is also customisable to be dynamic.
Clarified in the below image:


The formula presumes that the dates are real dates in the data table.
Cell H28 and drag across
=AVERAGE(IF(TEXT($H$21:$P$21,"mmm")=H$27,INDEX($H$22:$P$24,MATCH($G28,$G$22:$G$24,0),0),""))
AVERAGEIF works only with cells, therefore the following formula uses AVERAGE function.
The rows can be modified, but when you expand the data table two arguments must be adapted in the INDEX function.

$H$22:$P$24 to $H$22:$P$xx
$G$22:$G$24 to $G$22:$G$xx
where xx is the last row of the table.
If you apply a table for the data range, then the formula can be modified to use the table's column names and then no changes are necessary since the table automatically expand the referenced columns in a table.


